# How to test for arrays in chai testing framework?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test the values returned from a Fibonacci sequence method. I have created a test that checks if the result is equal to the Fibonacci sequence.

```
describe('#fibonacciSequence(myNumber)', () => {
    it('should return a fibonacci sequence', () => {
        const result = fibonacciSequence(10);
        const fibSeq = [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55 ];
        expect(result).to.equal(fibSeq);
    });
});
```

I get the following assertion error.

```
AssertionError: expected [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55 ] to equal [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55 ]
      + expected - actual
```

I can't figure out why I am getting an error even though the result is correct. I tried using `chai arrays` but that didn't work

Comment: You make it correct, but you've forget objects and arrays are not simple values so `[1,2]===[1,2] //false` so wrap `result` and `fibSeq` in `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: But I understand your confusion `jest` for example don't need this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

```
expect(result).to.equal(fibSeq);
```

is a strict equal and the expected array and result array do not hold the same reference. Therefore not equal

you can try using deep equal to see if the array results are the same

```
expect(result).to.deep.equal(fibSeq);
```

Answer (score 0):

You make it correct, but you've forget objects and arrays are not simple values so:

```
[1,2]===[1,2] //false
[1,2]==[1,2] //false
```

So wrap instead `result` and `fibSeq` in `JSON.stringify()` like this:

```
describe('#fibonacciSequence(myNumber)', () => {
    it('should return a fibonacci sequence', () => {
        const result = fibonacciSequence(10);
        const fibSeq = [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55 ];
        expect(JSON.stringify(result)).to.equal(JSON.stringify(fibSeq));
    });
});
```